# Create a .jar file from some *.so files using perl scripts

Tags: perl, jar

I need to create a .jar file out of few .so files using perl scripts

Answer (score 2):

This is not generally possible.

A `.so` (shared object) is a library that can be loaded dynamically, like a `.dll` on Windows systems. These libraries contain natively compiled code, and may depend on other libraries in turn. A `.jar` is an archive for the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). It too can be loaded dynamically, but it contains `.class` files that contain code compiled for the JVM.

Which much hackery, you could perhaps translate a program in machine code to JVM byte code (or write an emulator e.g. for the x86 architecture), but it would be *excessively* difficult to do, as the execution model of a CPU and the JVM differ substantially, e.g. in their treatment of memory. The result would likely be highly inefficient. And re-compiling a dynamically loaded library would be rather unportable, thus defeating the purpose of the JVM.

If you simply want to interface with a native library from the JVM (e.g. a program written in Java), then you could use the [Java Native Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_native_interface) (JNI) instead. In that case, you'd have to write a C or C++ wrapper around the `.so`, and would then be able to call the functions.

I have no idea why you mentioned Perl. While a nice language, it cannot help here.

Comment: You could put a `.so` inside a `.jar` file in the same way you can put a duck inside of a turkey.  Would it be useful?  Maybe, maybe not.  You could not execute it as a program, but it would be a `.jar` file all the same.